# Unable to load images in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I got stuck with loading images in react-native. I went through all the solutions given in the similar questions posted but the answers are not helpfull in my case. I tried importing the images like how we do in react like using import or require but both the options are not working.

PFB code for your ref

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardTitle, CardContent, CardAction, CardButton, CardImage } from 'react-native-material-cards';
import aboutImage from "https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg";
import {
  Button,
  View,
  Text,
  ScrollView, StyleSheet
} from 'react-native'

class About extends Component {

  handleScroll = e => {

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView onScroll={this.handleScroll}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>Who we are</Text>
          <Card style={{backgroundColor: "#fff", boxShadow: "2px 3px #3333"}}>
            <CardImage 
              source={{uri:aboutImage }}
              title="About US"
            />
            <CardContent text="Testing" />
          </Card>
      </View>
    </ScrollView>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    margin: 20
  },
  text:{
    color: "#06357a",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 30,
    fontFamily: "FreeSans,Arimo,Droid Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"
  },
  text1:{
    color: "#06357a",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontFamily: "FreeSans,Arimo,Droid Sans,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"
  }
});

export default About;
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```

### Edit

I tried downloading images to local and use require to import them but I get below error

> error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module
>   `../../../../assets/AboutUS.jpg` from
>   `D:\react-native\AppUsingRN\components\Layout\components\About.js`:
>   The module `../../../../assets/AboutUS.jpg` could not be found from
>   `D:\react-native\AppUsingRN\components\Layout\components\About.js`.
>   Indeed, none of these files exist:

I imported it like

```
   <CardImage 
          source={{uri: require('../../../../assets/AboutUS.jpg')}} 
          title="About US"
        />
```

I am not able to figure out the issue.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the image and providing its direct link as source? Like: `source={require('/assets/images/pexels-photo.jpg')}`. Not a solution but still something you can try for troubleshooting in the meanwhile.

Comment: I tried that as well but no luck.

Comment: @UzairA. I get error If I do in that way. Can you please check my updated question

Comment: You don't need `uri` when you are using `require`. Just `source= {require('link-to-image')}` would work. Also, please double-check the link to the image in project directory. Is the image actually present in that directory?

Comment: Hi @HemadriDasari, have you got any solution?

Answer (score 2):

It should work with:

```
<CardImage 
  source={{ uri: "https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg" }}
  title="About US"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not working somehow. I tried this.

Comment: Do I need to add any presets in .babelrc for loading images?

Comment: Here is a snack that works on my phone: https://snack.expo.io/@mtkopone/brave-bananas

Answer (score 1):

if use `require`

```js
const imageByRequire = require('../../../../assets/AboutUS.jpg');
<CardImage
  source={imageByRequire}
  title={'About US'}
/>
```

if use `uri` directly

```js
const imageByUri = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg";
<CardImage
  source={imageByUri}
  title={'About US'}
/>
```

If "It's not working somehow", maybe downloading or download error(there would be nothing), perhaps you can plus `defaultSource`.

```js
const imageByUri = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg";
const defaultImage = require('../../../../assets/AboutUS.jpg');
<CardImage
  defaultSource={defaultImage}
  source={imageByUri}
  title={'About US'}
/>
```

hope helpful :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but for some reason the valid answers are not working